# Java : Unable to change 'Content-Disposition' attribute in the Header for a response

Tags: java, http-headers

Below is the code:

```
Resource resource = getResource(request, requestUrl, userInfo, objectIdParam,
        rootFolderId, pathInfo, overrideCharset, isThumbnailResource);

// New line added to change Content-Disposition
response.setHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + pathInfo );

if (resource != null && resource.isServable()) {
    resource.serve(request, response);
}
```

As you can see, I have explicitly tried to change the 'Content-Disposition' to 'attachment' in the Header. But still, when I open an MS Office document, the HTTP Header data shows it as 'inline':
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="New%20Microsoft%20Office%20Word%20Document.docx"

Do you think I should do anything else to set this right?

Comment: Maybe your response is already committed?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the `resource.serve` method call internally overwrites the header with its own value.

[The javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#setHeader%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) says :

> If the header had already been set, the new value overwrites the
>   previous one. The containsHeader method can be used to test for the
>   presence of a header before setting its value.

Comment: Spot on ... how could I miss it !!! Thanks man ... the resource.serve method does alter the response header. So, I think I should be doing overriding just before throwing the response to output stream.